# Statistical consequences of random sampling or longitudinal (i.e., repeated) sampling

Tags: sampling, sample-size, statistical-power, survey

I need to assess the effect of different treatments on a crop. I am using a completely randomized block design with 4 treatments and 4 replicates for each treatment. The variables I need to measure are:

- The percentage of infested plants
- The percentage of infested leaves in infested plants

These measurements are performed on a weekly basis.

I am not sure whether it is better to perform a random sampling of the plants in each plot (i.e., every week I select a number of random plants) or to perform a longitudinal sampling (i.e., every week, I perform the measurements on the same plants).

What are the consequences from a statistical point of view? In particular, are there changes in:

- The sample size required?
- The power of my analysis?
- The type of statistical tests I need to use?